# Changing the value of a checkbox by inheriting a value in React.js

Tags: javascript, inheritance, reactjs

I'm trying to get familiar with how inheritance works between components in react.js and I'm having a bit trouble.

**Requirements** - Basically, what I want to achieve is for the value of my check box to change when I click on the button.

The check box is inheriting the value of `'checkedVal'`, which is set in state in the Heading.

I can get the correct value in the checkbox when it first loads but cannot change it when I click on the button. Any ideas would be appreciated?

```
var Heading = React.createClass({
propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    age: React.PropTypes.number
},
getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
        name: 'Keir',
        age: 24,
    }
},
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        manU: false,
        checkedVal: false
    }
},
manUFan: function(){
    this.setState(function(previousState, currentProps){
        return {
            manU: !previousState.manU,
            checkedVal: !previousState.checkedVal
        }
    });
},
render: function(){
    var msg;
    if(this.state.manU){
        msg = "I am a United fan."   
    } else {
        msg = "I dream of being a united fan."   
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Attempting React</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>{this.props.name}</li>
                <li>{this.props.age}</li>
            </ul>
            <button onClick={this.manUFan}>Do You Support Man U?</button>
            <CheckBox checkBoxVal={this.state.checkedVal}/>
            <p>{msg}</p>
        </div>
        )
}
});

var CheckBox = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        checkBoxVal: React.PropTypes.bool  
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.props.checkBoxVal}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
    });


ReactDOM.render(<Heading />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> The defaultValue and defaultChecked props are only used during initial render. If you need to update the value in a subsequent render, you will need to use a controlled component. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

So in your case here's how you'd implement a controlled `CheckBox`.

```
var Heading = React.createClass({
...
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            checkedVal: false
        }
    },

    handleChange: function(event){
        this.setState({checkedVal: event.target.value});
    },

    render: function(){
        ...
        return (
            <div>
                ...
                <CheckBox onChange={this.handleChange} checkBoxVal={this.state.checkedVal}/>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CheckBox = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        checkBoxVal: React.PropTypes.bool  
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.props.onChange} value={this.props.checkBoxVal}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe I've got this wrong but doesn't the 'onChange' value within the 'CheckBox' component need to be 'this.props.onChange'.